# Running SoapUI test from Java

Tags: java, rest, soapui

I am trying to run SoapUI test from Java. I prepared a project in ReadyApi and it is using Rest service and two steps. In a first step (groovy script), I set up test case properties (loading values from JSON) and a second step is Rest request. If I submit the request from ReadyApi, everything is going well and I get the proper response.

But if I tried to execute this test case from Java, I get following responses:

> 08:23:03,028 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
>   08:23:03,029 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /Process/op/execute HTTP/1.1
>   08:23:04,391 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>   08:23:04,396 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
>   08:23:04,396 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Target requested authentication
>   08:23:04,398 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Authorization challenge processed
>   08:23:04,399 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Authentication scope: BASIC @endpointAddress:443
>   08:23:04,399 INFO  [HttpAuthenticationRequestFilter$UPDCredentialsProvider] endpointAddress:443 requires authentication with the realm 'null'
>   08:23:04,400 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Found credentials
>   08:23:04,403 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 2 to execute request
>   08:23:04,403 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /Process/op/execute HTTP/1.1
>   08:23:09,061 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   08:23:09,062 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
>   08:23:41,067 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection closed

My Java code:

```
List<TestSuite> testSuiteList = new ArrayList<TestSuite>();
    List<TestCase> testCaseList = new ArrayList<TestCase>();

    SoapUI.setSoapUICore(new StandaloneSoapUICore(true));

    TestRunner testRunner = null;
    try {
        WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject("C:/Users/User/soapui - projects/rest-soapui-project.xml");
        testSuiteList = project.getTestSuiteList();
        Map<String,TestProperty> propertyMap;

        for (int i = 0; i < testSuiteList.size(); i++) {
            testSuiteName = testSuiteList.get(i).getName();

            System.out.println(testSuiteName);
            testCaseList = testSuiteList.get(i).getTestCaseList();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < testCaseList.size(); i++) {
           testCaseName = testCaseList.get(i).getName();
            propertyMap = testCaseList.get(i).getProperties();
            for (Map.Entry<String, TestProperty> entry :
                    propertyMap.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                TestProperty value = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println(key);
                System.out.println(entry.getValue().getValue());

            }
        }
        testRunner = project.getTestSuiteByName(testSuiteName).getTestCaseByName(testCaseName).run( new PropertiesMap(),false);

    } catch (XmlException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SoapUIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at documentation? https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/junit/junit-integration.html.  Also, you do have any settings / preferences customized ? If so, you may need to pass them too. By the way, were you able to execute the project using utility `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/testrunner` successfully? this is just to isolate the issue.

Comment: You are getting `401 Unauthorized ` error from the log. So please check the request that you are sending. By the way, if the project is build from Pro and running it with free edition, it may not work.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response, but I did not have time. I am able to send this rest request from SoapUI Free. The test step has basic authentification set up and specific header. How can I add basic auth to TestRunner?

Comment: How do you add that manually to be able send the request successfully? And once you set the test cases in the project, you should be able run it using java. Isn't the case?

Comment: I am able to send the request manually from Soap UI free and ReadyApi with the positive response, but I cannot send it from java code and I get Unauthorized. So I, though, that I need to add credentials into run(new PropertiesMap(), false);

Comment: How can I run soapUi rest tests from java. WSDL is for running SOAP tests.